# row added to mysql when browser is refreshed

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form where I can add some information. Those information is saved in MySQL database. The insert function is inserting the information I set in the form, but everytime I hit submit I am getting the error: `ERROR: Could not execute $sql`.

The information is inserted in the database correct, but I am still getting the error at the frontend.

The other problem is that everytime I refresh my browser, go back in the browser or hit submit without data in the form, there is still added empty rows in my database. Is there something that I am doing totally wrong here?

> Updated code after comments:

**insert.php**

```
<?php
$sql = "INSERT INTO stores (headline, description, place) 
        VALUES ('".$_POST["headline"]."','".$_POST["description"]."','".$_POST["place"]."')";

if(mysqli_query($res, $sql)){
    echo "Records added successfully.";
} else{
    echo "ERROR: Could not execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($mysqli);
}
```

?>

**index.php**

```
<div>
    <h4>Insert Store</h4><hr>
    <?php include 'function/insert.php' ?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="headline" value=""></input><br><br>
        <textarea name="description" rows="10" cols="30"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="text" name="place" value=""> 
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: simple: you queried twice `$res = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if(mysqli_query($res, $sql)){` and probably trying to insert an existing record that probably has a constraint.

Comment: and use a header

Comment: `mysqli_error($res)` you used the wrong variable here; it should have been `mysqli_error($mysqli)` and not the variable for the result set.

Comment: you can also drop the `</input>` it isn't a valid closing tag.

Comment: When you refresh the browser after a submit, it will submit the form, and of course it will insert another record. Add field validation before you insert the record so you don't insert empty records.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I removed the dublicate query, but still getting the error: `ERROR: Could not execute INSERT INTO stores (headline, description, place) VALUES ('test','test','test'). Invalid characterset or character set not supported`. How can that be? My column in the database is `varchar`. @Sloan: Ok, I will see if I can find some tutorials with that.

Comment: we don't know which variable is used for the connection here; is it `$res` or is it `$mysqli`? question's unclear at this point in time and if you want to avoid empty fields, check for empty inputs and/or don't allow NULL/empty values in your table.

Comment: Hello Fred. Argh shoot, now I see when you said `$res` and `$mysqli`. I changed the `$res` to `$mysqli`. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome Mimi.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> The other problem is that everytime I refresh my browser, go back in the browser or hit submit without data in the form, there is still added empty rows in my database. Is there something that I am doing totally wrong here?

That's because you included the insert.php regardless of the user-action.
You should remove the include-line and set your insert.php in the form's action field

```
<form method="post" action="function/insert.php">...</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried what you wrote here and made a test. When I hit submit I am redirected to `http://localhost:8888/fantasies/function/insert.php`, and there I am also getting the error: `ERROR: Could not execute INSERT INTO fantasies (headline, description, place) VALUES ('test1','test1','test1').` , and there is no record in my database.